# Special custom shortcut

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to create a special shortcut that minimize all windows and switch my current desktop to the next one. Could be useful for work.

I'm on Fedora 21 with GNOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a script that does the following:

```
xdotool key super+d
wmctrl -s <desktop#>
```

and bind that to the key you want. You probably have to install packages before you can use the commands (`sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl` on Debian based systems).

As a bash script moving back to the first window (counting starts at 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool key super+d
wmctrl -s 0
```

Comment: Those tools are great but I must miss something, I don't understand how an action is linked to the shortcurt with your command ?

Comment: You have to put these two together in a script, AFAIK there is no single command that can do both the minimize-all-windows and then switch. And that script you call from a shortcut (which depends on your desktop environment).